# Access Textblock Placed in Slider Thumb

Tags: c#, silverlight, datatemplate

I have placed a textblock in a slider thumb by Template editing. I want its value to be changed dynamically but the problem is I cant  access that text box from code behind.

Any Solutions??

Comment: you need to look into [TemplateBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189062(v=vs.95).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you give the `TextBlock` a name, you could use `VisualTreeExtensions.GetVisualDescendants()` to search the visual tree until you find the element with the name and type you're looking for.

For example:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

Slider slider = new Slider();
TextBlock tb = slider.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<TextBlock>().First();
```

You'll need to have a reference to the Silverlight Toolkit, namely `System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll`